# Mysql Regular Expression, a bit complicated one

Tags: mysql, regex, expression

I got a table in my database with field of "Name", one cell can contain more than one name by '|' that breaks them, for ie: 'NAME1|NAME2|NAME3' or another cell: 'NAME1'.
I want to select all the rows that contains the EXACT name, the problem is, lets say someone searching for 'BLABLANAME1' or just 'NAME' or 'AME1', none of this should return him the row, I tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE REGEXP '^NAME\||\|NAME$|\|NAME\||NAME'
```

Doesnt work at all, MySql returns error... I simply got no clue how to search for such a thing..

Comment: you didn't even specify the field to search...

Comment: yap. pretty retarded from me. anyway, I did now, and im getting: #1139 - Got error 'empty (sub)expression' from regexp. not much at google about this error... im pretty new to Mysql even tho this is a general regex...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**

```
SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE `the_name_column` REGEXP '^([^\|]+(\\|))*THE_NAME_YOU_SEARCH_HERE((\\|)[^\|]+)*$'
```

This will match the exact value of one of the values separated by "|", try to replace "THE_NAME_YOU_SEARCH_HERE" with one of the name value (one of the name in one column XD) in your database, and dont forget to escape it.

Comment: You didnt understand me well, the name that I search for is static per request, meaning its only 'NAME', and there arent duplicated of names in my table (if row #2 got "Steve" it wont appear again in the entire table), BUT some of the rows contain one name, while the other contain more than just one, and then the names are getting breaked apart by the character '|'

Comment: Actually, I used the link you provided and got to a working regex, works over there at least. At my mysql server your regex and mine, both give the same error: #1139 - Got error 'empty (sub)expression' from regexp

Comment: '^([^\|]+(\\|))*hello((\\|)[^\|]+)*$'

Comment: Great, thanks :) what was the problem ? EDIT: nvm, just saw we escaped the ver bar wrong.

Comment: you have to add double slash before the "|" in mysql hahaha. "(\|) became "(\\|)".